# Wordpress Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permissions

I am running wordpress on my own managed server so I have complete access to the box.  The issue I'm having is that users can upload images to my image library but any uploaded are not loading due to 403 errors.

When I go directly to one of the images I get the message "Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe"

I have set the permissions on the .htaccess file and all files to 775 but it made no difference.

I also tried nuking the file and uploading a new .htaccess from a fresh wordpress download in case it was corrupted but it made no difference.

The strange thing is the images do display in one context, when you use the wordpress image editor.

Not sure what to do about this, I'm a drupal developer and only have a passing familiarity with wordpress.

Example working legacy image:

http://www.bonnybridgeanglingclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSC_0671.jpg

Example broken recent image:

http://www.bonnybridgeanglingclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/652-1024x640.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should also check the permissions of the document root directory of your domain name. Try with

`chmod 755 /path/to/directory`

Comment: Already tried that, sorry, I forgot to include that in my description above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that for some reason when the 2017 directory was created inside the uploads folder it was created with the wrong permissions, very odd, I've fixed the permissions and all is well now.